# Why do some "Plain Old Ruby Objects" go in app/models directory instead of lib direcory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a project where the current developers have put their "Plain Old Ruby Objects" in the `models` directory of our Rails app.

I have seen most examples online where the PORO files go inside `lib` instead, but some say models.

Is there even a logical / specific reason why people put them in the `models` directory over the `lib` directory?

Comment: Why would you put them in `lib` over `models`?

Comment: There is an excellent blog post about this topic: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/. In general, you put application logic into `app/` and potential library code into `lib/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Idiomatically" the models directory intended for code used to hold state.  Most of the time this would be ActiveRecord subclasses corresponding to database tables.  However frequently people put other stuff in the models directory.  One thing often seen are code dropped here in order to take advantage of auto-reloading.  (the lib dir doesn't normally auto-reload)

Comment: I don't think that is true. Idiomatically the models directory is the right place to put models, regardless of whether they inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` or are involved in data-persistence. Nothing requires your models to be ActiveRecord objects: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#model-classes

Comment: I agree, models don't have to extend ActiveRecord::Base, but in practice they usually do.  But the idea is persistence, whatever mechanism is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Getting Started Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), the `app/models/` directory is pretty much anything, whereas `lib/` is for modules that are used across the entire app (e.g. extensions).

As @seand said, yes, one advantage is that the `app/models/` directory automatically reloads, but I tend to think of it as any class that "interacts with other classes" should live in `app/models/`, with the only exception being a service class (which I tend to think of as "a class which manipulates the state of another class"), which I tend to put into `app/services/`.

I know a lot of developers would disagree with me - many I've talked to even create a separate directory namespaced to their app (e.g. if your app is named "MyBlog", they would create an `app/myblog` directory for any object not explicitly backed by the database, but not a module or a service class either.

That said, I think ultimately it boils down to a) personal preference and b) where *you* feel is best to place the PORO with respect to your app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule on where to put POROs. The rails community has been hashing this out for a while now. At one point the convention was to put stuff in the concerns directory but that seems to have fallen out of favor with some folks.

One rule of thumb for the difference between /lib and app/{blah} is that code in the /lib folder is code that you presumably can reuse across several projects e.g. general purpose class or utilities. for example if you have some custom monkey patches to core ruby or rails classes that you will use in multiple projects, a good place to but them would be in the lib folder. Anything in app/{blah} should pertain specifically to current project.

One way to think of lib folder is as the poor cousin of plugins and gems.

Just my 2 cents on the subject